# How to edit the last few characters of a file?

Tags: python-2.5

I'm making a small program to trace the execution flow of a program.  I have some files that have source code and some that don't.  For calls that happen in files without source, I'm trying to count them and tack that number to the end of the output line.

From what I understand I'm positioning the cursor 3 characters from the end and then when I write `output` to `myfile`, it should have overwritten the previous 3 characters.  But when I look in the file, those 3 characters are just getting appended to the end.

```
with open("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\trace.html", "a+") as myfile:
                if hasNoSource and not fileHasChanged:
                    myfile.seek(-3,2)
                    output = line
                else:
                    self.noSourceCallCount = 0
                myfile.write(output)
            return self.lineHook
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a+" mode is open for append mode and any changes by seek() will be reset by next write().  Use "r+" mode.

Comment: I actually read that exact line but interpreted it to mean it reset the cursor after a write, not before.

Answer (score 0):

fileinput module with the inplace option allows you to modify your file but be sure to make a backup if all hell break loose

```
import fileinput,sys,re
line_count=0
for line in open(my_file): 
    line_count+=1                  # count total lines in file
f=fileinput.input(my_file,inplace=True)
for line in f:
    line_count-=1      #when iterating through every line decrement line_count by 1
    if line_count==0:
        line=re.sub("...$",<replacement>,line) #use regex to replace first three characters in the last line
        sys.stdout.write(line) #print line to sys.stdout which will automatically make the changes to this line in file.
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: Note <replacement> is where you input the character you desire